# Maven- Pom.xml properties not recognized in unitils configuration File

Tags: java, maven, unitils

I included my database configuration in pom.xml file in order to use them for my project testing ,I'm using unitils for database integration 
My pom.xml properties are

```
    <test.database.rules-satellite.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</test.database.rulessatellite.driver>
    <test.database.rules-satellite.server>localhost</test.database.rules-satellite.server>
    <test.database.rules-satellite.schema>R133_isp_copie_pdx</test.database.rules-satellite.schema>
    <test.database.rules-satellite.url>jdbc:mysql://${test.database.rules-satellite.server}/${test.database.rules-satellite.schema}</test.database.rules-satellite.url>

    <test.database.rules-satellite.username>junit</test.database.rules-satellite.username>
    <test.database.rules-satellite.password>junit</test.database.rules-satellite.password>
```

and my unitils configuration is as below :

```
# Properties for the`enter code here` PropertiesDataSourceFactory
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://${test.database.rules-satellite.server}/${test.database.rules-satellite.schema}

# This property specifies the underlying DBMS implementation. Supported values are 'oracle', 'db2', 'mysql' and 'hsqldb'.
# The value of this property defines which vendor specific implementations of DbSupport and ConstraintsDisabler are chosen.
database.dialect=mysql

# user properties
database.userName=${test.database.rules-satellite.username}
database.password=${test.database.rules-satellite.password}
database.schemaNames=${test.database.rules-satellite.schema}
```

When I run tests I get following error :

**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION**

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
MESSAGE: ${test.database.rules-satellite.server}
```

STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ${test.database.rules-satellite.server}
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1202)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
```

I think maven properties not being  propagated that's why unitils doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use maven resources plugin with filtering option. More detailed explanation can be found here: http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering/#TOC-Resource-filtering

Answer (score 2):

As Marcin Krasowski noted, you need to use the resources plugin, i.e. just add

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
       <directory>(path to the parent directory of your unitils conf file)</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Maven does not replace the `${}` variables in all files by default, you tell it to do so using the resources plugin.